# Number of ways to apply a symmetric function taking any number of inputs to $n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have a function that takes at least two inputs, no upper bound. Also, the order of the inputs doesn't matter. If I have $n$ inputs, what is the number of ways I can pass them to the function to get the final answer (the structure forms rooted trees since we always end up with one result, the "root")? This is a follow-up to the following question: [Number of ways to apply a function taking any number of inputs and producing one output to $n$ items](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076739/number-of-ways-to-apply-a-function-taking-any-number-of-inputs-and-producing-one). The key difference is that some of the trees that were being counted there could be converted into each other by permuting the leaves (does that mean they weren't "topologically distinct"?). So for three inputs, while the count of trees in the link is $4$, the number of "topologically distinct" ones is actually $2$.

Here, I'll draw the first few trees in the sequence:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I captured all trees with $5$ leaves, but am not completely sure. If we go with this, the sequence becomes: 1,1,2,5,13,...

Searching this in OEIS leads to the following page: http://oeis.org/A001519

This describes (among other things) "Number of ordered trees with n+1 edges and height at most 3". Which doesn't sound right.

So, what is this sequence? Is there a recurrence that can help me generate it for arbitrarily large values of leave nodes, $n$ (or better still, a closed form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is asking about the combinatorial class
$\mathcal{F}$ where

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{U} \times \mathcal{Z}
+ \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{MSET}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{F}).$$

We first  compute these trees  by the  number of nodes  represented by
$\mathcal{Z}$ classified by the number  of leaves and then extract the
coefficient  on the  number  of  leaves, which  are  marked here  with
$\mathcal{U}.$  Translating  to  generating functions  and  using  the
exponential formula for the multiset operator we find

$$F(z,u) = uz + 
z \left( 
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} \frac{F(z^\ell, u^\ell)}{\ell} \right)
- 1 - F(z,u) \right).$$

We introduce $F_n(u) = [z^n] F(z,u)$ to get

$$F(z,u) = uz + 
z \left( 
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} \frac{1}{\ell}
\sum_{q\ge 0} F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell} \right)
- 1 - F(z,u) \right).$$

Differentiating with respect to $z$ we obtain

$$F'(z,u) = u + (F(z,u)-uz)/z \\ + 
z \left( 
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} \frac{F(z^\ell, u^\ell)}{\ell} \right)
\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell-1} \right)
- F'(z,u) \right).$$

This is

$$F'(z,u) = F(z,u)/z \\ + 
z \left( ( (F(z,u)-uz)/z + 1 + F(z,u)) \times 
\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell-1} \right)
- F'(z,u) \right)$$

or alternatively

$$F'(z,u)/z - F(z,u)/z^2 + F'(z,u) \\ =
(1-u + F(z,u) + F(z,u)/z) \times
\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell-1} \right)
.$$

Extracting the coefficient on $z^{n-2}$ we obtain
for the LHS

$$n F_n(u) - F_n(u) + (n-1) F_{n-1}(u)
= (n-1) (F_n(u) + F_{n-1}(u)).$$

We get for the first piece on the RHS

$$(1-u) [z^{n-2}] 
\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell-1} \right).$$

Here we must have $n-2 = q\ell-1$ or $n-1=q\ell.$ We find
$$(n-1) (1-u) \sum_{\ell|(n-1)} 
\frac{1}{\ell} F_{(n-1)/\ell}(u^\ell).$$

We get for the second piece

$$\begin{align*} & [z^{n-2}] 
\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) z^{q\ell-1} \right)
(F(z,u) + F(z,u)/z)
\\ & = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}
\sum_{q\ge 1} q F_q(u^\ell) 
[z^{n-1-q\ell}] (F(z,u) + F(z,u)/z)
\\ & = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/\ell \rfloor} q F_q(u^\ell) 
[z^{n-1-q\ell}] (F(z,u) + F(z,u)/z)
\\ & = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/\ell \rfloor} q F_q(u^\ell) 
(F_{n-1-q\ell}(u) + F_{n-q\ell}(u)).\end{align*}$$

This gives the recurrence for $n\ge 2$ where $F_0(u) = 0$ and
$F_1(u) = u$:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{align*}
F_n(u) & = - F_{n-1}(u) 
+ (1-u) \sum_{\ell|(n-1)}
\frac{1}{\ell} F_{(n-1)/\ell}(u^{\ell}) \\
& + \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} 
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/\ell \rfloor}
q F_q(u^\ell)
(F_{n-1-\ell q}(u)+F_{n-\ell q}(u)).
\end{align*}}$$

As an example we have

$$F_5(u) = u^4 + u^3.$$

The reader is invited to replicate these trees from the number of
leaves. We also have as another example

$$F_{10}(u) = 
{u}^{9}+6\,{u}^{8}+16\,{u}^{7}+12\,{u}^{6}.$$
This says that e.g. there are sixteen of these trees on ten nodes
having seven leaves.

We get for the count of our trees the sequence
$\{F_n(1)\}_{n\ge 0}$ which is

$$0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 19, 35, 67, 127, 248, 482, 952,
\ldots $$

which points  us to  [OEIS A001678](https://oeis.org/A001678)  where a
considerable  amount of  material both  theoretic and  applied can  be
found.  We quote from the definition  of the sequence which says it is
the  "number of  unordered rooted  trees  with $n$  nodes where  nodes
cannot  have out-degree  $1$." This  is precisely  the meaning  of the
combinatorial  class we  have  used so  we know  we  have the  correct
answer.

Now to collect the trees with $m$ leaves on some number of nodes
we first observe that we need at least $m+1$ nodes (this gives the star 
graph). On the other hand the maximum number of nodes happens in a full 
binary tree on $2m-1$ nodes. Therefore the number of trees with $m$ 
leaves where $m\ge 2$ is given by

$$G_m = \sum_{q=m+1}^{2m-1} [u^m] F_q(u).$$

We also have $G_1 = 1.$ If we desire a single formula for $m\ge 1$
and don't mind a zero term for $m\ge 2$ we may also use

$$G_m = \sum_{q=m}^{2m-1} [u^m] F_q(u).$$

This gives the sequence $\{G_m\}_{m\ge 1}$ which is

$$1, 1, 2, 5, 12, 33, 90, 261, 766, 2312, 7068, 21965, \ldots $$

Note that  the diagram  by OP  for $m=5$  contains a  duplicate (trees
number   two   and  three).   The   sequence   points  us   to   [OEIS
A000669](https://oeis.org/A000669) where we learn  that this object is
known as a "series-reduced planted tree  with $n$ leaves" and there is
much more.

Here is  some Maple code for those who  are interested in working
with these sequences.  (The variable names originate  with the MathJax
above.)

```
with(numtheory);

F :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, ell, q;

    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return u fi;

    res :=
    - F(n-1) +
    (1-u)*add(1/ell*subs(u=u^ell, F((n-1)/ell)),
              ell in divisors(n-1)) +
    1/(n-1)*
    add(add(q*subs(u=u^ell, F(q))*
            (F(n-1-ell*q)+F(n-ell*q)),
            q=1..floor((n-1)/ell)), ell=1..n-1);

    expand(res);
end;

G := m -> local q; add(coeff(F(q), u, m), q=m..2*m-1);
```

Comment: Thanks! It'll take some time to digest this. First, I'm not familiar with the notation in your first equation. How do I learn more about it? Particularly how you went from there to the generating function.

Comment: Thanks to you. This notation is from *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick in particular page 27 which also has the generating function.